# Geoserver - disable root layer for WMS service with multiple layers

Tags: web, gis, geoserver, wms

How can I remove/disable root layer in WMS service (workspace) where multiple layers are available?

Geoserver allows the user to remove/disable root layer from WMS service in which there is only one layer (this layer is root instead then).

[image: https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/data/webadmin/layers.html]

(See 'Root layer in Capabilities' section)

This works fine when you have one layer (screen from QGIS and GetCapabilities response)

[image: WMS service with 1 layer and with NO root layer]

But it does not work when you add more layers to the same workspace

[image: WMS service with 2 layers and with root layer]

Is there any option to remove/disable root layer in WMS service (workspace) serving more than 1 layer?

I've tried also witch modifying specific workspace 'root layer' settings (disabled option 'Always include Root Layer in Capabilities' and cleaned 'title' and 'abstract' field) but with no result..

I'm working on Geoserver ver 2.23.2 installed on remote linux server (Ubuntu 22.04.1)

Comment: I think if you have multiple layers they have to be in something

Comment: That's how it usually is, and it sounds logical :)
but I have a specific ESRI module (swipe map tool) where I want to add such data served by geoserver, and this module requires me to serve the layers on a top level (as root layer) not as a layers in group.
The workaround is to create separate workspace for every single layer, but the problem is that I have quite a lot of layers to serve so in this way I would have a mess in my geoserver workspaces structure..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is only one possible setting in the GeoServer WMS to control top level elements in the capabilities, which is in [the WMS Services page](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/webadmin.html#root-layer-information), from the manual:

> It is also possible to set the flag `Always include Root Layer in capabilities`. This is checked by default, but can be unset so that the root layer is included in capabilities only when there is NOT already a single top level Layer element. This can be useful to allow compatibility with some WMS clients that are not happy with the two or more layer tree levels. This default setting can be overridden at the layer or request level.

If that doesn't solve the issue, you either need to ask for a GeoServer enhancement or try to get the client fixed.

Comment: This setting (Always include root layer..) unfortunately works only when you have exactly one layer. In case of two or morae layers it doesn not work, even if the seeting is unchecked

Comment: I feared that would be the case